# Can not add row when widget column is hidden

Tags: extjs

I have a grid, which is in a panel, there are two widgetcolumn in the grid.
If I click the 'Add new row' button, there will be a new row.

Now, if I hide one widgetcolumn, and then click the 'Add new row' button, nothing happend.

Here is the [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3q0f).

p.s. If I change panel to tabpanel, everything works fine.

I follow source code ext-all-debug.js, I find that the store add a new row, but the grid view not refreshed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to set an explicit height for the grid to ensure consistent and expected rendering.Changing the panel to a tab panel may have triggered a more controlled layout behaviour, resolving the issue with adding new rows. If you want to continue using a regular panel, make sure to set an height for the grid.

Check the [Updated Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3q0f)!